# How to prevent a function being called multiple times? (locking)

Tags: async

With a function that calls an asynchronous process, it's possible to call the same function multiple times.

What is a reliable way to avoid this that properly handles `quit` and errors being raised?

Is there an lisp convention for how to handle this?

---

This is an example of locking function, I'm wondering if there are better ways to handle this (existing macros or conventions for e.g).

```el
(defvar my-fn--lock nil)

(defun my-fn ()
  (unless my-fn--lock
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (setq my-fn--lock t)

          ;; Code body.
          (do-stuff))

      ;; Protected.
      (setq my-fn--lock nil))))
```

Comment: What you've done, and what @phils suggested, are the ways I've seen this kind of thing done. And what you did is the more common approach, I think. (It's not specific to function invocation, for example; it's used for testing whether some code has already been loaded or executed.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a symbol property: `function-put` to add or release the lock on the function symbol, and `function-get` to query the state.

Tangentially, `C-h i g (elisp)Mutexes` is a thing; but that's not what you're looking for here.

Comment: Could you show an example of how this would work?

Comment: Just like your approach, but instead of `(setq my-fn--lock VALUE)` you would `(function-put 'my-fn 'NAME VALUE)` and instead of evaluating `my-fn--lock` you would `(function-get 'my-fn 'NAME)` (for whatever arbitrary NAME you chose).  It just means you're not defining a separate variable which isn't used in any other context.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `unwind-protect`, this example shows how it can be done in a macro:

```el
;; Generic macro:

(defmacro with-lock-var (var &rest body)
  "Set VAR to t while in the scope of BODY, use to implement locking."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `
  (unwind-protect
    (progn
      (setq ,var t)
      ,@body)

    ;; Protected.
    (setq ,var nil)))


;; Example use:

(defvar my-fn--lock nil)

(defun my-fn ()
  (unless my-fn--lock
    (with-lock-var
      ;; Code body.
      (do-stuff))))
```